# Is there a C or C++ embeddable library for reading email through pop?

Tags: c++, c, pop3

I'm looking for a not too big C or C++ library that would allow to read email through pop on Windows. The smallest the better. It would be better if it could support SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also this [CPJNOPO3Connection](http://www.naughter.com/pop3.html) which supports ssl.

I have not used this library but the [SMTP](http://www.naughter.com/smtp.html) one with great success both on Windows and Windows CE

Answer (score 1):

Chilkat has [a bunch of libraries here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-library.asp) that are pretty good, lots of options.

Comment: I had bad experience with Chilkat library. I used xml classes at a time and they weren't very good (can't remember why ) and I had to change. Do you have some experience with chilkat pop3 ? It was some years ago, things may have improved.